# How to make Opera Mini the default browser?

Tags: stock-browser, default-applications, opera-mini

I have tried many times to change my phone browser from the stock android to Opera mini... As you all know the stock browser is slow and unresponsive.

Before I get overloaded with comment: YES I HAVE CLEARED THE DEFAULT FOR THE STOCK BROWSER THEN TRIED CLICKING ON A LINK. And: NO it has not asked me what browser I want to use. IT just opens in stock.

I then tried installing Firefox. I did the whole process again. I went to open a link and hit "open in browser" and what do you know, it opened up in firefox! This was great to see.

Unfortunately I can't get this to work for opera. Although firefox mobile is great I have a preference towards opera. If anyone knows of a solution to this I would apreciate it greatly.

Comment: It works fine with Opera Mobile.

Answer (score 4):

It works with Opera Mobile, it should be the same for Opera Mini.

You can try this:

- go to the default Android browser apps settings and click on "Clear defaults"
- if settings in Opera Mini has a "Set as default" check box, select it
- open a link with a browser and select Opera Mini as default

If the above doesn't work:

- uninstall Androids default browser

Answer (score 1):

For Android users, it's simple. Go to:

*Settings › Applications › Manage Apps*, chose *All Apps*, scroll to the *Browser*, tap that entry, and hit the button to *Clear Default settings.*

Then as you use the message links, select Opera as the default browser.

Answer (score -1):

One can't simply uninstall android stock browser. Because it should be installed as a system app. If you are rooted, then you can.

Comment: OP didn't ask to delete the stock browser – so this does not answer the question, sorry.